# How do I use emerge to install zynaddsubfx presets?

Tags: installation, command-line, sound

I found a script on the internet for installing zynaddsubfx presets but when I tried to use it on the command line I wasn't able to run it. Here is where I get stuck:

```
emerge -s zynaddsubfx.
```

This is what it says:

```
No command 'emerge' found, did you mean: command 'vmerge' from package 'util-vserver' (universe)
Command 'merge' from package 'rcs' (universe)
Command 'fmerge' from package 'fhist'(universe)
Command 'smerge' from package 'tstools' (universe)
Command 'emerge' not found.
```

Can anyone tell me how to use emerge?

Comment: Related: [Can I install Portage, Pacman or other package managers on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161503/can-i-install-portage-pacman-or-other-package-managers-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `emerge` command it is a command from (and will work in) [Gentoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux) and will never work in Ubuntu (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161503/can-i-install-portage-pacman-or-other-package-managers-on-ubuntu) in this sense). Its equivalent in Ubuntu is `apt-cache`. So, you should change `emerge -s zynaddsubfx` with:

```
apt-cache search zynaddsubfx
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to install it immediately use:

```
sudo apt-get install zynaddsubfx
```