# How can I install a pacman package on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 18.04

I somehow need to make a package through a `pkgbuild` file. On 18.04 the `makepkg` command is not found. How could I get pacman package installed?

Comment: what package are you attempting to install? Is it from the AUR?

Comment: i'd like to install the pacman package , in order to be able to execute the makepkg commnand

Comment: you can't use `pacman` on ubuntu see [[https://askubuntu.com/questions/161503/can-i-install-portage-pacman-or-other-package-managers-on-ubuntu/161506]] . What is the package you are attempting to make

Comment: I have a PKDBUILD file and would like to build the package from . Thought I could cd to the directory and run a makepkg command .

Comment: @Pascal That can only be done in distros using pacman as the package manager, namely Arch Linux and derivatives (such as Manjaro). You CANNOT use that on Ubuntu. You should find a .deb file, a PPA or even a repo for the Ubuntu equivalent of your package, or switch to Arch Linux (or some derivative)

Comment: Is it a `pkgbuild` to build pacman?

Comment: It's a pkbuild to build the Projucer from juce.com