# Portage or Portage like program for Ubuntu

Tags: apt, compiling

I saw this question [Can I install Portage, Pacman or other package managers on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161503/can-i-install-portage-pacman-or-other-package-managers-on-ubuntu), that it wasn't a good idea to install portage on Ubuntu because of how tightly bundled it is with gentoo. The reason I want to install it is for managing things I compile from source. I don't want to compile everything I just want the ability to manage what I do choose to compile from source. I would like to be able to point at a git repository build from it, and then use it. If I decided later that I didn't want the application anymore instead of remembering where I installed it I could use a package manager to remove it. Also updating with it would be nice, by specifying a release to upgrade to. I was wondering if there was an application like that, that worked for Ubuntu?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

Comment: @user535733 Does that mean you have to uninstall anything that you make and reinstall every time there is an update?

Comment: @user535733 yeah, but that doesn't really take advantage of make. If I pull in more files from source for an update, I don't need to remake all the binaries I only need to remake the binaries that are related to the update. It seems kind of overkill to uninstall it.

Comment: You need to do your own research on Checkinstall to decide if it's for you. It is well-documented.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for your help.

Comment: Aside: Debian is always looking for folks who enjoy the building process. Debian's corps of volunteer package maintainers is a key element in the success of all Debian-based distros. It can be a very rewarding hobby.

Comment: @user535733 I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

In the current state of the technologies you can have isolated Gentoo base system inside your Ubuntu by using containers like Docker or chroot/[schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot).
As long-time Gentoo fan I'll guide you in the process.

The below method explains how to implement `schroot` mechanism. We need to get [current stage3 snapshot](https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/) of Gentoo, then unpack it and configure according to [Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Full/Installation) but without disk partitioning.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install schroot -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/gentoo.conf
[gentoo]
description=Gentoo
directory=/srv/chroot/gentoo
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/gentoo

# add portage user and group
sudo groupadd portage -g 250
sudo useradd -M -g portage -s /bin/false -u 250 portage

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://bouncer.gentoo.org/fetch/root/all/releases/amd64/autobuilds/20210630T214504Z/stage3-amd64-20210630T214504Z.tar.xz

sudo tar -xf stage3-amd64-20210630T214504Z.tar.xz -C /srv/chroot/gentoo
```

Then you can jump to the newly created Gentoo schroot by using command below:

```
schroot -c gentoo -u root bash
# do something, then use Ctrl+D to exit to Ubuntu
```

To be assured that you have installed Gentoo system you can execute

```
schroot -c gentoo cat /etc/os-release
```

to get

> ```
> NAME=Gentoo
> ID=gentoo
> PRETTY_NAME="Gentoo/Linux"
> ANSI_COLOR="1;32"
> HOME_URL="https://www.gentoo.org/"
> SUPPORT_URL="https://www.gentoo.org/support/"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.gentoo.org/"
> ```

Then as example we can compile small graphical `xclock` application and Midnight Commander with default *make.conf*.

```
schroot -c gentoo -u root -- emerge --sync
schroot -c gentoo -u root -- emerge -qv x11-apps/xclock app-misc/mc
```

and finally launch the installed `xclock` application

```
schroot -c gentoo env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY xclock
```

Moreover you can operate the local data using applications which are installed inside Gentoo schroot:

1. activate schroot by `schroot -c gentoo`
2. then execute some command like `mc`
3. exit from schroot by using `exit` in the same terminal

I think you got the idea. By using such method you can have Gentoo inside your Ubuntu. This inner Gentoo can be configured by USE-flags, system profile and so on.
It will use Portage as you want.

---

If you like adventures then you can even install full lightweight desktop environment to this Gentoo system and run it in nested X11 system called Xephyr. Without details it is possible by doing the following:

```
schroot -c gentoo -u root -- mount /dev/shm /dev/shm -t tmpfs
schroot -c gentoo -u root -- emerge -atv mate-session-manager --exclude=dev-lang/rust
schroot -c gentoo -u root -- useradd polkitd
schroot -c gentoo -u root -- emerge -qatv mate-base/mate app-office/libreoffice-bin

mkdir ~/.gentoo # create new $HOME for Gentoo
Xephyr -screen 1360x680 :1 &
schroot -c gentoo -u $USER env HOME=~/.gentoo DISPLAY=:1 mate-session
```

to get something like

[image: Gentoo mate-session on Ubuntu]